# MySQL : Radio checked insert into database with multiple row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert two different data into a table with different row. If the only one data, it can be done. The problem occur when two data like in the picture.

This is my display html.
[image]

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" id="roomID" name="roomID" value="<?php echo $row['roomID']?>">
            <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $i++?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['room_name']?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['number_room']?> </td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="status" value="1" required> Available</td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="status" value="2" required> Not Available</td>
        </tr>
 }
```

This is to insert into database. I have tried using **foreach** to loop insert to table but it insert only one data.

```
$data = $_POST['status'];
$id = $_POST['roomID'];

    $sql = 'UPDATE `booking_room` 
     SET `available` = '.$data.'
    WHERE id_hotelroom = '.$id.'';

    mysql_query($sql);
```

Is there any other solution that i havent notice/figure can solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: I have found the solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is looping. But some correction to do in html.

```html
<?php
 $i = 0;
 foreach ($rows as $row) {
 ?> 
   <tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="roomID" name="row[<?=$i?>][roomid]" value="<?php echo $row['roomID']?>">
    <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $i?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row['room_name']?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['number_room']?> </td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" name="row[<?=$i?>][status]" id="status" value="1" required> Available</td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" name="row[<?=$i?>][status]" id="status" value="2" required> Not Available</td>
   </tr>
 <?php
  $i++;
  }
?>
```

then You can loop and in php.

```
<?php 
    $data_array = $_POST['row'];
    foreach($data_array as $row){
        $room_id = $row[roomid];
        $status = $row[status];

        $sql = 'UPDATE `booking_room` 
         SET `available` = '.$status.'
        WHERE id_hotelroom = '.$room_id.'';

        mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

I am not sure that 
`name="row[<?=$i?>][roomid]"` 
or 
`name="row[<?=$i?>]['roomid']"`. Check with both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <input type="hidden" id="roomID" name="roomID[]" value="<?php echo $row['roomID']?>">
                <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $i++?> </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['room_name']?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['number_room']?> </td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" name="status<?=$row['roomID']?>[]" id="status" value="1" required> Available</td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><input type="radio" name="status<?=$row['roomID']?>[]" id="status" value="2" required> Not Available</td>
            </tr>
     <?php } 


foreach ($_POST['roomID'] as $key => $roomID) {
    $roomID =  $roomID;
    $status =  $_POST['status'.$roomID][$key];

    $sql = "UPDATE `booking_room` SET `available` = '".$status."' WHERE id_hotelroom = '".$roomID."'";

    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Almost sir . If there two data , the first data are store (based on the radio checked), but the second data did not store.

Comment: We have update the code. Please check and replay me.

Comment: It still same sir . It seems the **foreach ($_POST['roomID'] as $key => $roomID)** only loop once . I have thru other method , but still haven't found the solution of the looping